# Nav menu - Rendering dividing pipe characters

Tags: asp.net, html, algorithm, user-interface

I have a webcontrol with a handful of links displayed at the top, eg:

```
Link 1 | Link 2 | Link 3
```

Currently they're each an asp:Hyperlink. `Is there a clever solution for rendering out the dividing pipe characters?`

Currently they're within the containing placeholder. We can't make any guarantees about a given link always appearing. I don't want a really big if-statement, and I'm reluctant to render all the links purely in the code-behind...

**[Update]**

Thanks for pointing out that CSS is the way to go. It's certainly made things easier. We did, of course, need a cross-browser solution though.

The HTML list (*<ul>* & *<li>*) structure works a treat, as the **first-child** / **last-child** properties take care of the end of the list. *Note*: These are automatic - you don't have to assign them in the markup.

As we only needed pipe symbols, I used the border property. If you wanted, you could use the **margin-left** + **background** image CSS properties to have an image spacer instead.

Our solution:

*HTML:*

```
<ul class="navMenu">
    <li><a href="...">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
ul.navMenu li
{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0;
}

ul.navMenu a
{
    border-left: solid 1px #333333;
    padding-left: 0.4em;
    padding-right: 0.4em;
}

ul.navMenu li.first-child a
{
    border-left: none 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `a + a` CSS solution doesn't work across all browsers, unfortunately.

I typically mark up my list like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first-child"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="last-child"><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Not only does this provide better JavaScript hooks, but you can customize the left/rightmost element to turn off the border or adjust padding as necessary.

Comment: Creating a menu like the one mentioned in the question would best be done using this method. Sprinkle in a little CSS + images and you should get exactly what you want with easier to maintain code.

Comment: I would agree with this approach.  If you wanted to get fancy, you could use jQuery to add the classes dynamically and perhaps add extra effects to your menu.

Answer (score 0):

the CSS and/or JQuery method works great.  Some times you really might just want `<a></a> | <a></a> | <a></a>` though.

It might be worth your time to look at a couple of server side controls.  Depending on where you get the links (you said some might be missing?)  you could just use a  control, it has a  where you could put the |.  If the links are missing depending on who is logged in and some kind of user roles, maybe you can use the sitemap +  control, it too has a .